# Jquery, Javascript: Push a 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Would like to create array like this:

```
track[divID][wrapID]
```

I couldn't use `track[divID][wrapID] = wrapID`

cos some more will be added to 2nd dimension in another loop like this: `track[divID][wrapID,wrapID2]`

```
var track =[];
$("div").each(function() {

                        var wrapID = $(this).parent().attr('id')
                        var divID  = $(this).attr('id')

                        track[divID].push(wrapID)

                                                    });
```

the Error is **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined "**

What did I do wrong ? Many thanks.

Comment: FYI `track[divID][wrapID,wrapID2]` would just evaluate to `track[divID][wrapID2]` due to how the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't created a new array for the second dimension:

```
track[divID] = [];
track[divID].push(wrapID);
```

Otherwise `track[divID]` is `undefined` and doesn't have `push` method.

Comment: I'd suggest `track[divID] = track[divID] || []` to make sure he doesn't overwrite an existing array, since he says he's going to add more.